# How do I get a Swift UnsafePointer from an immutable non-class value?

Tags: swift

I want to be able to create an `UnsafePointer` from immutable values.

The simplest reproduction of what I've tried to do is as follows:

```
let number : Int = 42;
var pointer = UnsafePointer<Int>(&number);
                                 ^
                                 | Could not make `inout Int` from immutable
                                   value.
```

Since `Int` does not conform to `AnyObject`, I cannot use `unsafeAddressOf()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a [message in the [swift-evolution] mailing list by Joe Groff](https://lists.swift.org/pipermail/swift-evolution/Week-of-Mon-20151214/002866.html), you can simply wrap the variable in an array when passing the pointer to another function. This method creates a temporary array with a copy of the target value and even works in **Swift 2**.

```
let number : Int = 42
my_c_function([number])
```

In **Swift 3**, you can construct an `UnsafePointer` directly. However, you must ensure the array's lifecycle matches that of the `UnsafePointer`. Otherwise, the array and the copied value may be overwritten.

```
let number : Int = 42
// Store the "temporary" array in a variable to ensure it is not overwritten.
let array = [number]
var pointer = UnsafePointer(array)

// Perform operations using the pointer.
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work I'm afraid... Any ideas? https://iswift.org/playground?HluN5e

Comment: Ahh, it appears to be an object lifetime issue.
https://iswift.org/playground?C3hojU

Answer (score 0):

You can use withUnsafePointer.

```
var number : Int = 42
withUnsafePointer(to: &number) { (pointer: UnsafePointer<Int>) in
    // use pointer inside this block 
    pointer.pointee
}
```

Alternately, you can use the "$0" shorthand argument to access the pointer within the block.

```
var number : Int = 42
withUnsafePointer(to: &number) { 
    // use pointer inside this block 
    $0.pointee 
}
```

Here are some good notes about using UnsafePointer: https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/unsafepointer

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work for immutable values.

Comment: Right, but I'm assuming he's using "number" for an inout value in a function call. In which case, why would he want it to be a "let"? I bet it was made a "let" instead of a "var" by mistake.